# mosquitto (on windows) command not found

Tags: windows, command, mosquitto

I'm a newbie to `MQTT` and `mosquitto`. 
I recently installed `mosquitto` on my Windows OS using the Windows binary installation file on the website (http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/mosquitto/binary/win32/mosquitto-1.4.2-install-win32.exe).

However, when I try to run the mosquitto commands, it displays an error saying that the command is not found. Upon Googling this, I found the same instructions to download the binary installation.

Even when I open the mosquitto folder saved in my Program Files and try to run the broker application, the window opens for a split second and then shuts off.
I also have HiveMQ downloaded. Could that be the issue?

I cannot understand what I might have done wrong during the installation otherwise. Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of mosquitto, mosquitto_pub nor mosquitto_pub are gui programs. You will need to run them through cmd.exe or powershell or similar. So for example:

```
run cmd.exe
cd <path to executables>
mosquitto_sub -h test.mosquitto.org -t '#'
```

On the "command not found" error, did you follow the instructions in the installer for installing dependencies?

- OpenSSL - install 'Win32 OpenSSL vXXXXX Light' then copy dlls to the mosquitto directory - http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html
- pthreads - copy 'pthreadVC2.dll' to the mosquitto directory ftp://sources.redhat.com/pub/pthreads-win32/dll-latest/dll/x86/

Comment: Thank you! I'd not copied all the dlls properly.

Comment: @ralight i am getting this error followed your steps , the ordinal 314 could not be located in the dynamic link library mosquitto

Comment: Make sure you have all of the most up to date libraries and that you have the Visual Studio 2013 redistributables installed.

Comment: Make sure you use the Win32OpenSSL_Light-1_0_2j.exe otherwise it will not contain: libeay32.dll ssleay32.dll
Step 8: https://sivatechworld.wordpress.com/2015/06/11/step-by-step-installing-and-configuring-mosquitto-with-windows-7/

Answer (score 2):

As per the readme-windows.txt file (found under the installation director), the dependencies (OpenSSL abd Pthread) are not provided with the installer and needs to be installed separately:

- libeay32.dll ssleay32.dll from open ssl (Download the OpenSSL from [here](http://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/) and copy/paste these two dlls under mosquitto  installation director)
- pthreadVC2.dll (download the dll from [here](ftp://sourceware.org/pub/pthreads-win32/prebuilt-dll-2-9-1-release/dll/x86/) and paste under mosquitto  installation director)

Answer (score 1):

do not install win64openSSL, even you do have 64bit OS :)
as far as mosquitto is 32bit app, it will work with Win32OpenSSL only ...